# Typescript: Object is possibly 'undefined' even after using?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have these two statements

```
<ng-container *ngIf="board.members?.length">

<ng-container *ngIf="board.members?.length > 5">
```

I'm getting an error for the second statement

> error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
>
> 39                             <ng-container
> *ngIf="board.members.length > 5">

I'm wondering why the first statement doesn't contain an error, but the second statement does contain an error and how I can resolve this ?

Comment: Because `board.members?.length` _is_ possibly undefined. If `board.members` is undefined the whole expression evaluates to undefined. You avoid the type error, but it won't magically create a value.

Comment: I do have members?: IMember[]; as possibly being undefined. Is there way to check if length is undefined similar to using '?'

Comment: It's unclear what behaviour you actually want - what _should_ happen if the array doesn't exist at all? If that's the same, as far as this logic is concerned, as existing but having fewer than 5 elements, maybe `board.members && board.members.length > 5`. JS has various options for conditionally handling things.